# Какие символы нужно написать чтобы выполнилось данное условие в регулярном выражения?

Tags: python, python-3.x, re

прочитал про регулярные выражения и не могу выполнить данное условие.
Мне надо найти значение которые начинаются SN: и заканчиваются на пробел.

Вот мой код:

```
test = 'SN: kfowl1231 ','SN: qwrwl1231 lfwelfw\r ','SN: abc12345 info\r\t rtyqw '

res = re.findall(r'???', test)
print(res)
```

Вот результат который я хочу `res = 'SN: kfowl123','SN: qwrwl1231','SN: abc12345'`

Было бы еще круто чтобы выводило без SN:

что нужно поставить вместо ??? чтобы заработало ?

Comment: что за тип данных у вас в test? список, строка?

Comment: `findall(r'SN: (\w+) ', test)`

Comment: спасибо, эти значение берутся у словаря скорее всего это строка